# How to access the target socket in a Socket.io handler

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm working with a Socket.io server and I'm trying to access the socket that emitted the event from the client.

There's this example in the docs :

```
socket.on('private message', function (from, msg) 
{
    console.log('I received a private message by ', from, ' saying ', msg);   
});
```

Trying to use this, I've noticed that the parameter order has changed in the latest version and the 'from' parameter is actually a function.

I'm having trouble using this to get information about who emitted the event.

Is there another way? or perhaps a way using the parameter to get the info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the server, your code should be in a closure like this and you can access the parent function argument that contains the socket:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {

    // you can access the argument socket from the parent function
    console.log(socket);
    // access the socket id of this socket
    console.log(socket.id);

    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

If you want to use a named handler function, you can create a stub function that passes the socket to the named handler function like this:

```
function myEventHandler(socket, data) {
    // you can access the argument socket from the parent function
    console.log(socket);
    // access the socket id of this socket
    console.log(socket.id);
    console.log(data);
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    myEventHandler(socket, data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use named functions as handlers but I guess I'll do it like that.

Comment: @NickTsitlakidis - You can use a named handler, but you just have to create a stub function that passes the socket to the named handler.

Comment: You mean something like that?                                                  `socket.on('my other event', handleEvent); function handleEvent(socket,data){console.log(socket,data)}`

Comment: @NickTsitlakidis - I added an example to my answer using a named handler function.